# Aperture priority on Nikon DF doesn't work with pre-AI lens?

Tags: nikon, nikon-df

I just bought a 55/3.5 pre-AI.

In order to use aperture priority mode, I did these:

1. Raised the meter coupling lever
2. On Non-CPU lens data:
   focal length: 55
   maximum apperture: F/3.5
   exposure meter coupling: non-AI

As I'm changing the aperture, the indicator sticks at F/10. No wonder my photos are underexposed.
But with other AI/AIS lenses, the camera detects the lens aperture properly. And of course aperture priority works fine.

Is there something wrong with my 55/3.5 pre-AI?

Comment: You flipped the AI coupling lever up, of necessity, since the non-AI lens could damage it. But now there is no way for the camera to know automatically what aperture the lens is set to. There is nothing wrong with the lens. The problem is with the camera, because it lacks the pin that would couple with the rabbit-ears on the lens. (That was the way pre-AI camera and lenses communicated.) But the Df was never meant to have it.

Comment: Raising the meter coupling lever is mentioned in this: https://www.nikonusa.com/en/learn-and-explore/a/products-and-innovation/using-legacy-nikkor-lenses-with-the-nikon-df.html. Anyway, I got it: after you adjust the apperture ring, you have to turn the sub-dial command so the camera knows what the selected apperture is. Then Apperture Priority works fine. Kinda less convenient.

Comment: The whole point of AI is to support aperture priority....

Comment: @user3528438 No it isn't. See the Nikkormat EL from 1972, with pre-AI mount and aperture priority.

Answer (score 4):

The camera will not know the aperture set on the lens. So you have to set the same aperture on the camera and on the lens and it should work.

https://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/df.htm#lenscomp